# How to handle exception logging

Tags: php, exception

I have a complex web app that I am adding error logging to, I want to be able to log exceptions:

```
try{
//typically mysql queries but can involve PayPal api, Facebook api amongst others
        }
        catch($e){
            logger($e);
        }
```

Is it safe to assume $e will always be a string, if not is there a php function I can call which will always give me the string output of '$e', so that my logger can store the resulting output in my log table?

Comment: yes $e->getMessage();

Comment: $e ... a string? $e should be some instance of a child class of the Exception class which has a __toString method...

Answer (score 0):

It's not c++, it's php that is why you need to throw either **Exception** object or instance of object that is **subclass of Exception**

From PHP manual

> The thrown object must be an instance of the [Exception](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php) class or a subclass of Exception. Trying to throw an object that is not will result in a PHP Fatal Error.

So that is why you always have access to Exception class methods for example:

- final public string getMessage ( void ) //Gets the Exception message
- final public string getTraceAsString ( void ) //Gets the stack trace as a string

that is why you can use `catch(Exception $e){ echo $e->getMessage();}` to get message of exception or trace which are always string.

If you want to pass Exception object you can extend Exception class and override **[__toString()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/exception.tostring.php)**  method to fit your needs.

You can also be interested in [Setting Exception Handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php)